# Python AttributeError: module 'sklearn.externals.joblib.numpy_pickle' has no attribute 'NumpyArrayWrapper'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, anaconda, pickle

I got a deep learning code in python (anaconda 4.2), on Ubuntu 16.04. It basically detects ad frames inside a video. When trying to run it, I get an error. How can I fix it? I'm not a python/anaconda guy myself.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import time, cv2, librosa
import skvideo.io
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import subprocess, os, glob
from sklearn.externals import joblib
//...........
clf_trained = joblib.load('/home/myuser/Desktop/Detection_module/trainsvm_mfcc.pkl') 
//...........
```

And here are the errors:

```
​/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/skvideo/__init__.py:356: UserWarning: avconv/avprobe not found in path: 
  warnings.warn("avconv/avprobe not found in path: " + str(path), UserWarning)

 1 -th video being processed, /football_711.mp4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/Desktop/Detection_module/detection_main.py", line 21, in <module>
    Ad_module_textfast_final_backup.metadata_creation(cur_video_name)
  File "/home/myuser/Desktop/Detection_module/Ad_module_textfast_final_backup.py", line 105, in metadata_creation
    final_label_list, pred_labels_list= label_prediction( mfcc_list, num_frames= 3)
  File "/home/myuser/Desktop/Detection_module/Ad_module_textfast_final_backup.py", line 28, in label_prediction
    clf_trained = joblib.load('/home/myuser/Desktop/Detection_module/trainsvm_mfcc.pkl') 
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 459, in load
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1039, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1334, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 1388, in find_class
    return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.externals.joblib.numpy_pickle' has no attribute 'NumpyArrayWrapper'
```

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch. Please check the scikit (joblib) version where the pickle file was created versus where you are trying to unpickle it. They should be same

Comment: Yes I know that. But how can I check these? And how to change/remove the other one?

Comment: @TinaJ - can you check by replacing NumpyArrayWrapper with NDArrayWrapper in trainsvm_mfcc.pkl . It will be mostly in binary format with a mention of the wrapper class in initial lines.